# Android: Layout for dynamic buttons + FAB + Appbar

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button

I'm new to Android (and Java) and have difficulties with the layouts.

When I click on the FAB, a button should be created. As I learned, I must use LinearLayout when I want to add buttons programmatically. This is generally working, but when I try to combine the LinearLayout with the FAB and the appbar, either the newly created button is not shown or the FAB or the appbar.

One of the layouts hides always some of the other elements. It should look that way:

1. Appbar
2. LinearLayout - Buttons with scroll bar
3. FAB on the bottom right

I tried with RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, CoordinatorLayout etc., no luck.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xyz.mypackage.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!--include layout="@layout/content_main" /-->

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: how many buttons you want to create programmatically on fab click?If it is one, then create that button in the xml and set visibility to gone. When fab is clicked make it visible. Makes sense?

Comment: On fab click a dialogfragment is shown where you can enter a string and on OK click, one button is created with the string as name. I think it could work, I'll give it a try, thanks! I am also reading layout documentation, it should be possible somehow.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation (yes, I should have done that before posting a question), I found out a way to do it:

As root, use a RelativeLayout, then for the appbar and buttons use a LinearLayout as child (I also added a ScrollView with another LinearLayout). The FAB should be within the root (RelativeLayout) with the following attributes:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the button in the xml and set visibility to gone. Fab click triggers  dialogfragment, to take input you can include EditText.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.project_name);
if (editText != null) {
    Log.e("Value", editText.getText().toString());
    button.setText(editText.getText().toString());
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    Log.e("", "EditText not found!");
}
```

How to get Text from a EditText in a DialogFragment?

[getText from a EditText in a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037381/gettext-from-a-edittext-in-a-dialogfragment)